# Text Translation Issue

Tags: r, google-translate, sentiment-analysis, r-package

I am trying to do sentiment analysis in R on a Norwegian data. I was thinking of first converting the data into english and then going forward with the analysis.
But for the conversion we are having to send the data outside the client network(using Google translate), which the client is not ready to accept. Is there any package in R by which we can do the sentiment analysis on the Norwegian dataset itself without having to transmit the data outside??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This paper](http://folk.uio.no/paalee/publications/2014-cse.pdf) documents the creation of a sentiment lexicon in Norwegian and says "All the sentiment lexicons are publicly available for those that are interested", so I would suggest contacting the authors.